# Trouble initiating background process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous

I have a node.js/express setup with the code below. The client side code is built with React. They are able to query X number of players using fetch from 1 to whatever they want. The query is sent to my express server, which sends requests to Riot Games public api. The issue I'm having is if the query is too large, the fetch times out.

Someone gave me the idea to have the initial POST request return an "id" and then run the actual query in the background. Then have the client's browser periodically check if the query is complete with a GET request.

I'm calling the initial POST inside React **componentDidMount()** and then I'm sending the GET request inside **componentDidUpdate()**. I think where I'm messing up is with when I'm sending the get request and also with how I'm initiating the background process. I'm pushing the result of the query to an allResults[0] array. The **playerRequest** is an async function.

Hoping I explained that well enough... not really sure what to do.

**src/server/index.js**

```
var playerSearch = require('./playerSearch.js');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '!'));

var allResults = [];

//Beginning of all methods
app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => res.send({ username: 'Summoner' }));

app.post('/api/champstats/initiatePlayerSearch', async function(req, res){
  var searchID = uuidv1();
  allResults.push(await playerSearch(req, searchID));
  console.log('Search ID: ' + searchID);
  return res.send({searchID: searchID});
});

app.get('/api/champstats/playerSearch/:searchId', async function(req, res){
  const result = await allResults.filter(x => x.requestID === req.params.searchID);
  return res.send({stats: result[0].stats});
});
```

Comment: Does removing the `await` to `playerSearch` fix it? (well, the post part, at least... the get will need to be changed...)

Comment: Also, make `allResults` either an object or a map, and instead of pushing, put the promise from 'playerSearch` under the searchID key, so you can look it up in the get...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately removing await did not work. My browser is still timing out with the following error: "net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch". I did put allResults into an object too. I should have done that in the first place.

Comment: And that failure is coming from the `/api/champstats/initiatePlayerSearch` request? (`/api/champstats/playerSearch/:searchId` still could time out the way it is currently written)

Comment: The failure is currently coming from the `/api/champstats/playerSearch/:searchId` (GET) request. I think perhaps I need to call this request periodically until it succeeds (or fails), but I'm not sure how to do it. Right now I'm calling it immediately after `/api/champstats/initiatePlayerSearch` returns the searchID. The searchID updates my React components state, which calls **componentDidUpdate**. Inside **componentDidUpdate**, is my GET request, which is only called once. This request times out, because **playerSearch(req)** is still processing data.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the promise in the async result endpoint, but also timeout if the result has not been fetched yet:

```
var playerSearch = require('./playerSearch.js');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

const {promisify} = require('util');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('dist'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + port + '!'));

var allResults = {};

const timeout = promisify(setTimeout);

//Beginning of all methods
app.get('/api/getUsername', (req, res) => res.send({ username: 'Summoner' }));

app.post('/api/champstats/initiatePlayerSearch', async function(req, res){
  var searchID = uuidv1();
  allResults[searchID] = playerSearch(req, searchID);
  console.log('Search ID: ' + searchID);
  return res.send({searchID: searchID});
});

app.get('/api/champstats/playerSearch/:searchId', async function(req, res){
  const searchResult = allResults[req.params.searchID];
  const result = await Promise.race([ // return the first result you get
    timeout(100).then(async ()=>null), // wait for 100ms then return null.
    searchResult # if the search result returns before 100ms, use that as the result
    ]);
  if (result != null){
    return res.send({stats: result[0].stats});
  } else {
    // return an error message so you can try again later
  }
});
```

There are a few variants of how you can do this pattern with async await instead of using `.then`, if you wanted to experiment with those. One thing to note though, any callback for the timeout probably shouldn't respond to the request, because it won't be cancelled if the other promise returns first. All promises passed to `.race` will eventually finish, so if you are calling methods on `res`, keep that in mind. `.race` doesn't cancel pending promises.